# RegExp replace one html tag by another with some exceptions

Tags: html, regex, ms-access, vba

I need to change some html tags by others.

For example, I want to change the

```
<EM></EM>
```

tags to

```
<strong></strong>
```

tags, except when the word inside the

```
<EM>
```

tags is et al, ie.:

```
<EM>et al</EM>.
```

Is there a way in which I can use a single replace operation for matching the EM word inside the the start and closing tags

```
<> </>
```

or the only way is by using 2 replacement operations, like

```
"(<EM>)(?!et al)", "<strong>"
```

**Edit:**

I'm using VBA inside MSAccess.

This is my UDF:

```
'--------------------------------------------------------------------
' Name:         RegExpReplace
' Purpose:      Replace text in a string using Regular Expressions.
' Requires:     Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
' Author:       Diego F.Pereira-Perdomo
' Date:         Dec-27-2012
'--------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function RegExpReplace(ByVal strInput As String, _
                ByVal strPattern As String, _
                ByVal strReplace As String, _
             Optional booIgnCase As Boolean = False, _
              Optional booGlobal As Boolean = True) As String

    Dim oRegExp As RegExp
    Dim strOutp As String

    Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    With oRegExp
        .IgnoreCase = booIgnCase
        .Global = booGlobal
        .pattern = strPattern
        strOutp = .Replace(strInput, strReplace)
        RegExpReplace = strOutp
    End With
    Set oRegExp = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: What language/tool do you use?

Comment: Is your exception strictly `<EM>et al</EM>` or should `<EM>Someother text and et al</EM>` be left as it is as well?

Comment: I'm using the DOM inside VBA for parsing thousands html strings. Problem is that I don't like the structure they have and I'm completely transforming them into different strings. Note that I'm saying strings, not documents because I'm not putting these htmls in my disk. Since you suggest to do this with the DOM, how you'll do it? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @Vache, until now is just et al, but is possible that I'll need to exclude other texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

After some research about regex capabilities with VBScript (and VBScript syntax), the simpliest way seems to be:

```
Dim re: Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "<em([^>]*)>(?!carmen</em>)([\s\S]*?)</em>"
re.Global = True
re.IgnoreCase = True

Dim str: str = "<em class=""truc"">where</em> in the <eM>world</em> is <em>carmen</em> sandiego?"
Dim rep: rep = "<strong$1>$2</strong>"

MsgBox re.Replace(str, rep)
```

Pattern description:

```
<em             # literal: <em
([^>]*)         # capture group 1: all characters except > zero or more times
>               # literal: >
(?!carmen</em>) # lookahead assertion: not followed by "carmen</em>"
(               # capture group 2:
    [\s\S]      # all that is a white character + all that is not a white character
                # = all possible characters (including newlines)
    *?          # repeat zero or more times (lazy)
)               # close capture group 2
</em>           # literal: </em>
```

The pattern is designed to exclude exactly "carmen". If you want to exclude substrings that contains "carmen", you must make some change to the pattern and take care to not check the word outside the tags (`<em>blah blah blah</em> carmen`)

the most simple way:

```
<em([^>]*)>((?:(?!carmen)[\s\S])*?)</em>
```

*note that this way is particulary inefficient since the regex engine must check `(?!carmen)` for each character.*

An other way:

```
<em([^>]*)>((?:[^<c]+|c(?!armen)|<(?!/em>))*)</em>
```

This pattern seems to be a good idea, but there's a problem. All works fine when the string contains the closing tag `</em>`, but if the closing tag is missing your script will simply crash because of catastropic backtracking. You can find more information about this [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).
A way to solve the problem is to use an [atomic group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) `(?>..)` (inside which the regex engine is not allowed to backtrack) in place of the non capturing group `(?:..)`, but VBS regexes (as Javascript) doesn't have this feature.
However you can emulate this feature using a lookahead, a capturing group and a backreference: `(?=(pattern))\1` is equivalent to `(?>pattern)`. *(because a lookahead is naturaly atomic)*

If I rewrite the precedent pattern with this trick, I obtain:

```
<em([^>]*)>((?:(?=([^<c]+|c(?!armen)|<(?!/em>)))\3)*)</em>
```

Comment: Thank you @Casimir et Hippolyte I'll try that. Don't understand the negative vote... anyway...

Comment: Didn't work @Casimir et Hippolyte. Probably is because VBA doesn't allow backreference. Thanks again.

Comment: @Diego: it doesn't matter, I don't care about downvotes. Perhaps try with `\1` instead of `$1`.

Comment: @Diego: vba doesn't support possessive quantifier `++` (I just remember that). Try now

Comment: I edited my first post for adding the function I'm using.
With the expressions you have posted I'm getting a Run-time error 5017: Method Replace of object 'IRegExp2' failed.
Vba doesn't support  backreference, so \1 shouldn't work in any case.

Comment: @Diego, since when? I've been using backrefs in vba back since 1960,... well maybe not 1960, but long ago.

Comment: hahaha @l'L'l I think I read that some time ago... but I can be wrong of course. FWIW I'm still getting the aforementioned error.

Comment: @Diego, I edited Hippolytes answer, although the change isn't visible yet, since it needs to be approved. I hope they don't mind, but it might not have been working because there was a zero-width match on \1.

Comment: Ok @l'L'l I'll wait until it gets visible. Thanks to you both.

Comment: @l'L'l: a zero width capturing group is not a problem.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte and l'L'l this is the expression RegExp doesn't like: "?>[^<]+|<"

Comment: So yes, RegExp doesn't complain with this expression but it does nothing: 

 ?RegExpReplace("<EM>hey</EM>","<em\b([^>]*)>(?!et al</em>)((>[^<]+|<(?!/em>))*)</em>","<strong\1>\2</strong>")
 
I can turn on or off the case sensitive search in VB RegExp without the (?i) so I removed it also because it triggers the error too.
Is the first question mark the problem... (?(>[^<]+|<(?!/em>))*)

Comment: @Diego, try using `<em\b([^>]*)>(?!et al</em>)((?:[^<]+|<(?!/em>))*)</em>` — in other words replace the `>` with `:`

Comment: Thank you @l'L'l. RegExp doesn't complain but doesn't replace the tag.

Comment: @Diego, Interesting — I guess the only thing at this point would be to post your code so someone can figure out why it's not working. RegEx is usually pretty straight-forward and this seems a bit odd. Have you tried doing a simple test such as using (et al) and just replacing that to see if it works?

Comment: @l'L'l yeap. I did it. The code I'm using for this is posted in my original post. The implementation of this is straightforward: RegExpReplace("<em>hey<em>","pattern","replace",True) or in the immediate window of VBA ?RegExpReplace("<em>hey<em>","pattern","replace",True).

Comment: I've use this function for over a year without any problems. For example this simple test works as expected: ?RegExpReplace("<em>hey<em>","<[A-Za-z]+>","<strong>",True) ---> Returns <strong>hey<strong>

Comment: @Diego, I see, well it must be something in the regex that it's still not liking, or another parameter needs to be set in your vba a particular way.

Comment: @l'L'l Thank you. I don't think the function is wrong but the expression. The function captures well the backreferences: `code`?RegExpReplace("<em>hey</em>","(<em>)[A-Za-z]+(</em>)","<strong$1>$2</strong>",True) ---> Result <strong<em>></em></strong>

Comment: This way works, but surely can be improved: `?RegExpReplace("<em>hey</em>","(<em>)([A-Za-z]+)(?!et al)(</em>)","<strong>$2</strong>",True)` Result `<strong>hey</strong>`

Comment: Nice @CasimiretHippolyte I tried your example and works great. I'll try it in my code ASAP.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte this is great and answers my original question: `<em>et al</em> in the <eM>et al </em> is <em> el al</em> sandiego?` Result: `<em>et al</em> in the <strong>et al </strong> is <strong> el al</strong> sandiego?`. The technique is very interesting. I appreciate the time you've taken in this.

Comment: @Diego: Some examples for your new requirements with the technique.

Comment: Many thanks @CasimiretHippolyte. I'll play with that in short. In the mean time, what do you think about my answer in terms of efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

This expression works perfect.

```
<(em)>((?!.*?et al).*?)</\1>
```

So essentially it captures

```
(em)
```

for using it in the end tag

```
</\1>
```

excludes the string even if there are characters before

```
(?!.*?et al)
```

or after

```
(?!.*?et al).*?
```

and captures the result

```
((?!.*?et al).*?)
```

Well, more the less that's what it does :)

For replacing using my function these are some examples:

Ex.1:

```
?RegExpReplace("<em>et al</em>", _
"<(em)>((?!.*?et al).*?)</\1>", _
"<strong>$2</strong>", _
True)
```

Result:

```
<em>et al</em>
```

Ex.2:

```
?RegExpReplace("<em>et al </em>", _
"<(em)>((?!.*?et al).*?)</\1>", _
"<strong>$2</strong>", _
True)
```

Result:

```
<em>et al </em>
```

Ex.3:

```
?RegExpReplace("<em> et al</em>", _
"<(em)>((?!.*?et al).*?)</\1>", _
"<strong>$2</strong>", _
True)
```

Result:

```
<em> et al</em>
```

Ex.4

```
?RegExpReplace("<em>et a</em>", _
"<(em)>((?!.*?et al).*?)</\1>", _
"<strong>$2</strong>", _
True)
```

Result

```
<strong>et a</strong>
```

Ex.5

```
?RegExpReplace("<em>t al</em>", _
"<(em)>((?!.*?et al).*?)</\1>", _
"<strong>$2</strong>", _
True)
```

Result:

```
<strong>t al</strong>
```

Note the use of the backreferences in the searching pattern and in the replacing string. In the searching pattern one has to use the backslash and the reference number; in the replacing string one has to use the dollar sign and the reference number.

Finally, I have to disagree with the notion that RegExp are not useful or moreover dangerous for editing html (docs or strings).

Parsing an html is easily accomplished with the DOM and that is the recommended tool with no doubt.

So I use the DOM for parsing the Html, extract the different parts and RegExp for modifying the details.

Hope this help others.

Regards,

Diego

Comment: The capturing group for the tag name is not useful since you know in advance the tag name. The pattern you use will fail if your string contains "et al" after the closing `</em>`, example: `<em>toto</em> et al`, because the lookahead doesn't check if you are inside or outside tags. In other words, `.*?` in `(?!.*?et al)` can match `</em>`. In fine, don't forget that `.` doesn't match newlines. About the DOM,I don't think that using the DOM is dangerous or difficult! It is like all, if you master it, you will not encounter problems. Good notice about `\ ` and `$` for backreference.